# ActionView::MissingTemplate, Rails 5 API with JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, api, ruby-on-rails-5

I am consistently getting an ActionView::MissingTemplate error when trying to render JSON in my Rails 5 Api. I just want to render the pure JSON, without a jbuilder or other view. Can anyone help?

thing_controller.rb:

```rb
class Api::ThingController < ApplicationController
  def thing
    render json: {error: 'This is my error message.'}, status: 422
  end
end
```

thing_controller_test.rb:

```rb
require 'test_helper'
class Api::ThingControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  test "the truth" do
    get '/api/thing'
    assert_response 422
  end
end
```

full error message:

> Error: Api::ThingControllerTest#test_the_truth:
>   ActionView::MissingTemplate: Missing template api/thing/thing,
>   application/thing with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:json],
>   :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby,
>   :jbuilder]}.

application_controller.rb:

```
 class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
    include ActionController::Caching
    include ActionController::ImplicitRender  # want implicit view rendering for JBuilder

  before_action :add_cors_headers


  def options
    head(:ok) if request.request_method == "OPTIONS"
  end
```

Comment: maybe try calling `to_json` on the Hash that you're returning as JSON?

Comment: try `format.json { render json: ... }`

Comment: Tried both of the above, neither worked. Thank you though!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is related to [an issue](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder/issues/317) in Rails 5 beta ActionController::API and Jbuilder. It looks like it has been fixed by this [pull request](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/24178/files).

Meantime you can return plain text and set the content type, like so:

```
render plain: {error: 'This is my error message.'}.to_json, status: 422, content_type: 'application/json'
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful.